# Spring boot Flux Rest end point

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, flux

I have a REST end point written in Java Spring boot, it is FLUX end point.
And here is a Java implementation of the Interface :

```
 public Mono<ResponseEntity<MyDTO>> postRequest(
         String fileName, Mono<Resource> body,
        ServerWebExchange exchange
    )
```

The service takes a name of the file as a parameter, and also a org.springframework.core.io.Resource in  body

```
 @Parameter(name = "fileName", description = "File name.", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
        @Parameter(name = "body", description = "XML file.", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Mono<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> body,
        @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
```

later  on some manipulations on the file are taking place :
One such method is :

```
  private Flux<String> parseFileAsString(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Flux<DataBuffer> requestBody = exchange.getRequest().getBody();
        return requestBody.map(buffer -> {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableByteCount()];
            buffer.read(bytes);
            DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
            return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        });
    }
```

I understand the usage of exchange parameter ServerWebExchange , it allows access to endpoint body and headerss, but why do I operate with the body via exchange, can I not just use the body that is passed into the method? this one: Valid @RequestBody Mono<org.springframework.core.io.Resource> body, can not I operate on it in order to get information out of it ?